Why can we assume that the $i^e$ component of a stationary distribution of Markov Chains is null if $i$ is transient?
In many exercises on finding stationary distributions of Markov Chains, my professor makes the following statement: if λ is an invariant distribution for $\Pi$ (the stochastic matrix for discrete-time homogeneous Markov chains) or for $Q$ (the generator for continuous-time homogeneous Markov chains), then for all states $i$ such that $i$ is transient, we can assume $\lambda_i = 0$.
I only need to show this for the discrete-time homogeneous Markov chains case because, by passing to the jump chain, the result will also hold for continuous-time homogeneous Markov chains.
However, I can't figure it out. Mainly because most theorems assume the chain is irreducible, and when this is not the case, I lose track of how to proceed.
If anyone has any indications or a proof of this statement, I would be very grateful.

A state $i$ is transient if and only if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \Pi^n(i,i) <\infty$. In this case,
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \Pi^n(j,i) <\infty$ for every state $j$.
In particular, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\Pi^n(j,i)=0$ for all $j$. But
$$
\lambda_i =\lambda\Pi^n(i) =\sum_j\lambda_j\Pi^n(j,i)
$$
for all $n$.
Now let $n\to+\infty$ and apply the dominated convergence theorem to conclude that $\lambda_i=0$. (And it's not really a matter of assuming...)
